# How to pass api data from one method to another within an object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, xmlhttprequest

I made a simple oject called 'weather' that has method inside.
The weather object should have three methods.

1. getWeather: Get weather data which is getWeather method which uses xmlhttprequest api to pull weather info and pass the weatherdata which is xhr.responseText to another method (callback) so that in the second method, I can destructure the weather data and save them to variables.
2. callback: Like explained, the callback method should get data from the getWeather method. However, i get an error saying **"uncaught TypeError: callBack is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload"**.
3. search is there to pass the function to the getWeather method when the eventListener is fired when clicked.

In summary, I just want to extract data from the getWeather method and pass that data to the callback

I want to do this without fetch.then or without promisifying my xmlhttprequest.

```
let weather = {

apiKey:'dcaa6d5ea6bc87524fd5e38257edabba',
city: 'montreal',   

getWeather: function (city, callBack) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(
        'get'
        ,`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${this.apiKey}`
        , true)
    
        xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);  
            // console.log(weatherData);
            console.log(weatherData);
            callBack()
        }
        
    }
    xhr.send()
},

callback: function () {
    console.log('weatherData')
},

search: function () {
    this.getWeather('new york')
}
```

};

```
document
.querySelector('.button')
.addEventListener('click', () => weather.search())
```

Comment: `callBack(weatherData)` and `callback: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
},` - though, in the code you've written you'd need to `weather.callback(weatherData)` since `this` won't be what you probably think it is

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the JavaScript engine cannot resolve what the value of the `callback` parameter of `getWeather` is when it is invoked in `weather.search` and also when the function you assigned to `xhr.onload` is eventually invoked when the request completes successfully.

There are several ways you can make sure the callback parameter or variable successfully resolves to the callback method of the weather object, which appears to be what you intended.

One: By supplying the argument for getWeather's second parameter: `callback` or by using default parameter value syntax to give that parameter a fallback value if it isn't supplied.

```
let weather = {

    apiKey:'dcaa6d5ea6bc87524fd5e38257edabba',
    city: 'montreal',   

    getWeather: function (city, callback = this.callback) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(
            'get',
            'https://randomuser.me/api/'
    // There is a 401 error interpreted as unauthorized for the api below, thus why the above api is used to test
    //         ,`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${this.apiKey}`
            , true)

            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                    const weatherData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);  
                    callback(weatherData)
                }

            }
        xhr.send()
    },

    callback: function (weatherData) {
        console.log(weatherData)
    },

    search: function () {
        this.getWeather('new york', this.callback);
        // the below also works
        //this.getWeather('new york');
    }

}
```

Two: By eager supply of some or all arguments of a function prior to invoking it via the engine provisioned closure method called bind on Function prototype.

In your case, a single parameter can be supplied to `getWeather`: which is `city` while a new parameter is given to the function assigned to `xhr.onload`, and that can be supplied a hard argument of `this.callback` by using `Function.prototype.bind`.

```
let weather = {

    apiKey:'dcaa6d5ea6bc87524fd5e38257edabba',
    city: 'montreal',   

    getWeather: function (city) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(
            'get',
            'https://randomuser.me/api/'
    // There is a 401 error interpreted as unauthorized for the api below, thus why the above api is used to test
    //         ,`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${this.apiKey}`
            , true)

            xhr.onload = function (xhrCallback) {
                if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                    const weatherData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);  
                    xhrCallback(weatherData)
                }

            }.bind(null, this.callback)
        xhr.send()
    },

    callback: function (weatherData) {
        console.log(weatherData)
    },

    search: function () {
        this.getWeather('new york')
    }

}
```

Finally, note that I had to use a `randomuser` api because the api in your question is not authorizing and you can swap it in back as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much SNOSeeds, first method worked perfect!

Comment: @masafood, that's great to hear! Kindly accept the answer as well then.

Comment: you mean upvote right? i would like to but onlything is its telling me to have a reputation of 15

Comment: I get that, apart from being able to upvote, you are able to accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. That is an absolute ability because you need that to let others know what worked out for your question. Look at this StackOverflow [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=As%20the%20asker%2C%20you%20have,best%20solution%20to%20your%20problem.) for that.